# .htaccess rewrite rules behaving in a wrong way

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm building an events website, in all my websites i do the following logic:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^new/event?(/)?$ controller.php?page_name=new-event [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^get-event/([^/]+)?(/)?$ controller.php?page_name=get-event&event_id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^event/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?(/)?$ controller.php?page_name=event&event_id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^event-edit/([^/]+)?(/)?$ controller.php?page_name=event-edit&event_id=$1 [QSA,L]

// this below line to handle all links that do not apply to the above rules, is this wrong?
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)?(/)?$ controller.php?page_name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The last line is to handle all URLs that don't have anything other than the page name, like those:

- `www.example.com/event-submit/`
- `www.example.com/about/`
- `www.example.com/contact/`

Because I made a `controller.php` file that handles all the requests depending on the `page_name` value.

But this is not working with this new site, here's what i get:

when I request any URL belonging to this site, the browser just hangs and takes forever, sometimes the page loads but after like 5 minutes.

I have no idea why! (It works on all my other websites!)

Am I doing anything wrong? I have searched a lot and nothing is working.

**EDIT**

This is controller.php: (it just checks for page_name if it's allowed and then includes it)

```
<?php
session_start();
define('__SITE_ROOT__', dirname(__FILE__));
define('__HELPERS__', __SITE_ROOT__ . '/' . 'helpers');
define('__APP__', __SITE_ROOT__ . '/' . 'app');

$page_name = strip_tags($_GET['page_name']);

$allowed_pages = array(
    'index',
    'about',
    'contact',
    'new-event',
    'event-edit',
    'get-event',,
    '404'
);
class Controller{
    public $page_name = 'index';
    public $allowed_names = array();
}
$controller = new Controller();
$controller->allowed_names = $allowed_pages;
$controller->page_name = $page_name;
if(in_array($controller->page_name, $controller->allowed_names))
{
    $page_real_name = $controller->page_name . ".php";

}else{
    $page_real_name = "404.php";
}
include(__APP__  . '/' . $page_real_name);
```

Comment: .htaccess has no wait time. It is most likely in your php code or may be database connection or filesystem

Comment: @anubhava the thing is that when it was hosted in a sub directory (/demo), everything was fine, but now when moved it to root, this happened.

Comment: Have you tested commenting out RewriteBase / ?

Comment: Yep, didn’t work, I’m going crazy over this

Comment: "when I request any URL belonging to this site" - What if you request a URL that _doesn't_ belong to your site? eg. `/foo/`.

Comment: @MrWhite, the browser just hangs whenever i request any URL that start with the website's domain, removing the last line would make the site work again, but i have to make a RewriteRule for every single page.

Comment: Yes, that is what I would have expected. Any URL that consists of a single path segment would cause the same problem, whether it's a valid URL on your site or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> // this below line to handle all links that do not apply to the above rules, is this wrong?
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)?(/)?$ controller.php?page_name=$1 [QSA,L]
> ```

This rule would create a rewrite-loop (500 error), since the regex `^([^/]+)?(/)?$` would also match `controller.php` (the URL being written to) and you don't appear to have anything that would otherwise prevent this?

You could resolve this my adding a dot to the character class, so it won't match the dot in `.php`. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)?/?$ controller.php?page_name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

You don't need to surround the last `/` in parentheses.

(I'm assuming the `//` *comment* is just in your question, since that is syntactically invalid. Comments are delimited with `#`.)

> the browser just hangs and takes forever, sometimes the page loads but after like 5 minutes.

However, the above doesn't quite explain this behaviour, unless maybe `LimitInternalRecursion` is set very high in your server config?! (Default is 10)

Comment: Oh, thaaaank you very much! you saved my day, yeah the '.' in the Rewrite rule saved the day and now everything is working after your answer, because i ended up making a very long RewriteRule to allow ALL the pages on my website, and it was very long.

Comment: is there a way to alter the last line to include all the url and not just the first slash?, because with this current rule, i can handle 404 (in my controller.php file) with just one url variable (.com/foo/), but if there're more (.com/foo/bar/baz) i get 404 Not Found document.

Comment: You're welcome, still curious regarding the response you were getting. You would expect something like this to break very quickly with a 500 Internal Server Error. (Unless maybe the "custom" 500 error document is also causing an error?)

Comment: "to include all the url and not just the first slash" - You can remove the slash from the character class, but you'll need to make the quantifier non-greedy so that it doesn't consume the trailing slash (as it is now). eg. `^([^.]+?)?/?$`

Comment: Yeah i also noticed that when `ErrorDocument 404 /404` is present the website hangs as well, even if i'm requesting an existing page. Removing `ErrorDocument 404 /404` would make the website run again!. I opened inspect element and looked in the network tab to see maybe there're some 404 XHR requests, but i found none.

Comment: I ended up using your last answer `^([^.]+?)?/?$`, it works perfectly!. But i did not understand what you said there `but you'll need to make the quantifier non-greedy so that it doesn't consume the trailing slash`. Should i not use it?

Comment: Your previous rule does not pass the (optional) trailing slash in the `page_name` parameter, so I was making it behave the same... The `+` quantifier is "greedy" by default, which means that it consumes as many characters as possible. So if you simply remove the `/` from the character class, it will also capture the "optional" trailing slash at the end and pass this to `page_name`. You make the quantifier non-greedy by appending a `?`, ie. `+?` is the non-greedy version of `+`. So, now, the optional trailing slash is not captured.

Comment: However, non-greedy quantifiers are less efficient (although you're not going to notice that here). The alternative is to simply pass the entire URL-path to `page_name` and let your PHP script handle the trailing slash. OR, make the trailing slash mandatory, so it's not consumed by the _greedy_ quantifier. eg. `^([^.]+)?/$` - now your URLs must end in a trailing slash (and this is not passed to `page_name`). However, this no longer matches the document root (homepage), ie. an empty URL-path - which your previous regex did.